# How can I reference an external javascriptfile in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to create a sliding menu for my aplication in angular, I would like to reference a javascript file. I have referenced css files in the `angular.json` file, but not js files, it's been a problem for both my own files and files imported from external libraries like bootstrap or jquery.

I've tried to use reference my js files in `index.html`, and referenced my scripts and styles in `angular.json`

angular.json

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",

              "src/assets/js/expanded-menu.js"
            ]
```

Comment: what is the issue with referencing in angular.json > scripts ?

Comment: The files are not loading, I'm referencing them in the same way I'm referencing the css files and they are not loading. I don't know if I have to reference them somewhere else

Comment: how did you check if they are loading or not?

Comment: also as a side note, if you are importing jquery in angular, you are doing it wrong

Comment: It just says the functions from my files were not found, a 404

Comment: 404 is a http response, how is it related to loading javascript? when you add js file to  scripts it will be bundled into 1 file, so you won't see that file and you shouldn't request that file, just use it's methods

Comment: that's what I've been trying to do, I can't access the methods

Comment: Please edit your original post and paste the code from your .ts file in which you are using this library.